# Evaluate variable based on user input

Tags: vba, excel

Coming from Python, I cannot figure out a way to accomplish my end goal since a function like eval() does not exist with Excel VBA.

Below is what I am trying to achieve by using a simple example that I can scale:

```
Dim userinput as String
userinput = inputbox("A=John, B=Kate, C=Tim", "Enter a letter that corresponds with your name: ")
Dim A as String
Dim B as String
Dim C as String

A = John
B = Kate
C = Tim

Dim Phrase as Variant
phrase = msgbox("Hello, my name is " & userinput)

Result:
User enters a C
msg box pops up as "Hello, my name is Tim"
```

Regardless of what I try to do, I cannot have a userinput correspond to a variable that is then interpreted while in a string. My macro would be useless without a user's input referencing a much longer and complex phrase that would be too hard for a user to enter on their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're presenting a finite, pre-determined set of options to the user.

Yet you let them enter quite literally *anything*, not validated, and roll with it.

A much better alternative would be to ditch the `InputBox` approach and present the user with an actual `UserForm`, so that the user's input is *constrained* to a finite, pre-determined set of options - a `ComboBox` control comes to mind:

[image: some UserForm with instructions, ok, cancel buttons and a combobox control]

The UserForm's code-behind is pretty straightforward - hide the form when a button is clicked, treat "X-out" as a cancellation, expose the user's `Selection` and whether the form was cancelled via `Property Get` members, and populate the dropdown with the possible values to pick from:

```
Option Explicit
Private isCancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = isCancelled
End Property

Public Property Get Selection() As String
    Selection = ComboBox1.Value
End Property

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    isCancelled = True
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    With ComboBox1
        .Clear
        .AddItem "Lorem"
        .AddItem "Ipsum"
        '...
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        isCancelled = True
        Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

And now you can do this:

```
Public Sub Test()
    With New UserForm1
        .Show
        If Not .Cancelled Then
            MsgBox .Selection
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This handles the user cancelling out of the prompt, and if your `ComboBox` control's `Style` property is set to `fmStyleDropDownList`, there's absolutely no way the user can supply a value you're not expecting. And you can extend it further by supplying `Property Get` and `Property Let` members to configure the `Title` and `Instructions` labels as needed, or make the calling code responsible for supplying the list of valid values to populate the `ComboBox` with.

That's *one* part of the problem. The next part is "mapping" inputs with another string value. The best data structure for this is a `Dictionary`, but a keyed `Collection` can work just as well:

```
Dim values As Collection
Set values = New Collection
values.Add "string 1", "Lorem"
values.Add "string 2", "Ipsum"
'...

With New UserForm1
    .Show
    If Not .Cancelled Then
        MsgBox values(.Selection)
    End If
End With
```

Of course there are *many* ways to populate the data you need here, both for the combobox values and the mapped strings in the collection; you can hard-code them like this, or get them from a `Range` on a worksheet, or from a database, whatever rocks your boat.

Comment: Oops, typo in the frame's caption. Oh well.

Comment: What language is that in the form? Definitely the correct approach btw.

Comment: @A.S.H [*Lorem Ipsum* comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC.](http://www.lipsum.com/) ;-)

Comment: I forgot that these existed! Thank you for the clarity in your answer. While more complex than a MsgBox, the validation of a ComboBox is definitely helpful.

Comment: @J.Squillaro the `InputBox` was originally made purely for providing quick debug/test values, *for developers*. It was never intended to end up user-facing. UserForms are extremely useful - and if you build them in an Excel add-in project, you can reuse them in all your VBA projects (and have consistent-looking UI in all your macros) if you make them flexible/decoupled enough.

Answer (score 2):

The user is typing a letter.  You need code to more explicitly translate that into a name.  There are a lot of methods - if you have a long list or a user-entered list you may need a solution that is more dynamic.  However here is a fix for your code:

```
Dim userinput as String
userinput = inputbox("A=John, B=Kate, C=Tim", "Enter a letter that corresponds with your name: ")
Dim A as String
Dim B as String
Dim C as String
Dim nameOut as String

select case userinput
    case "A"
         nameOut = "John"
    case "B"
         nameOut = "Kate"
    case "C"
         nameOut = "Tim"
end select

Dim Phrase as Variant
phrase = MsgBox("Hello, my name is " & nameOut)
```

Note: don't forget to enclose strings in double quotes.

Comment: This is a great solution as well. I will definitely keep it in mind if my code does not need absolute validation!

Answer (score 1):

Posted just because it's a different approach. It finds the position of the inputted letter in an array of all three, and then finds the corresponding item in an array of the names.

```
Sub x()

Dim userinput As String
Dim Phrase As String
Dim v

userinput = InputBox("A=John, B=Kate, C=Tim", "Enter a letter that corresponds with your name: ")
v = Array("John", "Kate", "Tim")

With Application
    If IsNumeric(.Match(userinput, Array("A", "B", "C"), 0)) Then
        Phrase = .Index(v, .Match(userinput, Array("A", "B", "C"), 0))
        MsgBox "Hello, my name is " & Phrase
    Else
        MsgBox "Wrong letter"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This approach is more easily adaptable to pulling a dynamic list from a range in Excel and should strongly be considered if you want to go that route

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from Scott's answer but for a potentially more dynamic approach it seems `class modules` and `callbyname` have an answer:

Class module - class1

```
Private pa As String
Public Property Get a() As String
a = pa
End Property
Public Property Let a(value As String)
pa = value
End Property
```

Test sub

```
Sub testing()
Dim cls1 As Class1
    Set cls1 = New Class1

cls1.a = "tim"

userinput = "a"

Debug.Print CallByName(cls1, userinput, VbGet)

End Sub
```