# Creating variable in userform and moving it to a module

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and and am trying to finish this project by teaching myself. I'm trying to make a userform with a ComboBox drop down menu of months and a textbox to enter the year. I then want to have those values saved as variables and transferred back to the main module. I have referenced [Assigning a variable directly from a userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381451/assigning-a-variable-directly-from-a-userform) and [Passing variable from Form to Module in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214072/passing-variable-from-form-to-module-in-vba), but what they did isn't working for me. [This is what my form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPDUo.png).

My form is named Dates. The Combo box is Correct_Month; textbox is Correct_Year. I want to save these values in variables Month and Year.

This is what I have for the userform:

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Correct_Month_Change()
Month = Correct_Month.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Correct_Year_Change()
Year = Correct_Year.Value
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
'Message box forces a response
If Correct_Month.Text = "" Or Correct_Year.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("You must enter a month and year to continue")
    Exit Sub
End If
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Correct_Month.Clear
Correct_Month.List = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", _ 
    "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", _
    "December")
Correct_Year.Value = ""
End Sub
```

This is my module:

```
Private Sub Monthly_Report_Test()

'~~> more coding

    Dates.Show
    'something here to call variables over?
    driver.findElementByName("Dates").SendKeys Month
    driver.findElementByName("Dates").SendKeys Year

    Correct_Info = MsgBox("Is the following information correct?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Report Month: " & Month & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Report Year: " & Year, _
        vbYesNoCancel, "Month & Year")

    If Correct_Info = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

'~~> more coding

End Sub
```

I've tried several different things and this is as close as I can get. Can anyone tell me what I need to do and why? Thank you so much!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43920726/1188513) gets you started with actual OOP code, no globals, no default form instance, no self-destructing objects.

Answer (score 0):

In vba you can get the value of control (=your combo box) from userform
by simply write the **NameOfUserForm.NameOfControl**

In your case - add to your module there lines :

```
Dim Var1, Var2
Var1 = Dates.Correct_Month.Value
Var2 = Dates.Correct_Year.Value
```

Now you can use the variables : Var1 & Var2 - as you want.

Comment: The problem with using the default instance and closing it with `Unload Me` is that as soon as the form destroys itself, its state is gone as well. The solution is to *not* unload the form (no self-destructing objects), use an actual instance (`New` it up yourself), and expose the state via properties - or better, via an interface that the form implements. That way the controls are encapsulated implementation details and there's no incestuous back-and-forth between the form and its callers. This answer would work for a buggy form that doesn't unload itself. Not the case with OP's code though.

Comment: He is new in VBA - and you offer things from OOP concept that are too complicated than he need.

Comment: Fair enough. That makes many more VBA questions to answer though, and many bad habits to undo later, when they *do* learn.